# Cloned Ubuntu 17.04 no ethernet

Tags: networking, 17.04, ethernet, lspci

I cloned my Ubuntu Server 17.04 from a virtualbox to a physical machine as that machine was serving so I wanted to setup a new one without taking down the current install. After replacing my old system with the img i made of the virtualbox machine everything worked fine, it booted fine and my stuff was all there except for my internet.

lspci shows my RT8111/8168/8411
ifconfig shows only virtualbox adapters and a enp0s3 adapter which I don't know what this is.

There does not appear to be a `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file anymore (Is this changed? it used to be there on my 15.04 install)

How do I fix this??

---

Output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

[image: OP's picture from comments under deleted answer]

Comment: Interesting. I'll look at this after I get back home. I might have an idea now as to what's going on.

Comment: Alright, I will wait for it.

Comment: Also, when I do `sudo ifup enp0s3` it returns `Cannot find device 'enp0s3'`

Answer (score 2):

Alright I happen to fix the issue,
After all I was looking at the wrong spots as @Kaz Wolfe suggested and I thought in the first place that *my* ethernet adapter was enp0s3 but after all it was enp2s0 I changed the `/etc/network/interfaces` file to be the following

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.254
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.0.0.0
    broadcast 10.0.0.255
    gateway 10.0.0.6
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 208.67.222.222
```

Then I simply ran `sudo service networking restart` and `ping google.com` and it worked!
It still does contain a lot of other network interfaces which I am not sure of what they are doing there but I think it has to do with docker and mapping ports so I will leave them alone.

Comment: This is "the proper answer" for ubuntu 15.x and later!